# Prove that $\lim _{x \to \infty} \sin x$ doesn't exist (using delta epsilon)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

though there is a question already asked in this site similar to this i want to prove  that  $\lim _{x \to \infty} \sin x$ doesn't exist using epsilon and delta.
I don't know how to do this because sin(${\infty}$) can't be determined.
someone please help me in this proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the response given by Belgi, here a version with your epsilon but missing a delta ;)

A function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is said to have a limit $L$ at infinity if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $c\in\mathbb{R}$ so that for all $x>c$ you have $\left| f(x)-L \right|<\epsilon$. 
Now the negation of this is:

There exists an $\epsilon>0$ so that for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$ there is an $x>c$ with $\left| f(x)-L\right|\geq\epsilon$

Now in your case for any $L\in [0,1)$ (the cases $L=1$ and $L\in [-1,0)$ are similar) you can choose $\epsilon=\frac{1-L}{2}$. Then for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$ set $x=\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi \lceil c \rceil$ and get
$\left| \sin(x)-L\right|\geq\epsilon$.

Comment: i couldn't understand 'the cases L=1 and L∈[−1,0) are similar' can you please explain me that

Comment: You need to find a different $\epsilon$ and $x$. The $x$ I chose is such that $\sin(x)=1$. This will have to be adapted. Maybe draw a sketch to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :find two subsequences, one that is always zero and the other is always one

Comment: i couldn't understand you explain me please

Comment: You should find two distinct sequences of x'es, $x^1_n \rightarrow \infty$ and $x^2_n \rightarrow \infty$, such that $\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty} \sin(x^1_n) \neq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin(x^2_n)$.

Comment: @AmpatishanArun this is Heine's theorem